# Merge multiple rows into 1 rows and multiple columns with Talend

Tags: multiple-columns, rows, talend

Input :

[image]

Output i want :

[image]

So i have 3 rows AND 1 column and it's always in  the same column from Excel file.

I will always have 3 column and i want convert that into 1 rows and 3 column.

How can i do that ?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify a bit please ? Can you add an example of your expected output ? is "A-> FirstName" a string in a single column ? For now this is not very clear.

Comment: Yes it is specified. Thank you for your remark.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with simple tMap and tAggregaterow. You'll have to get a fixed schema on your output, but as I understood this will be the case .
(firstname/hours/lastname)

[image]

[image]
tMap : for each output field, put the value of column B if column A matches name of output column. else null.

[image]

tAggregate to compress data to one single row using 'max' operation.